# Books to understand what's theoretical physics about

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations

I'm starting university, but I've not made up my mind yet: I like both physics and maths. I pretty much know what mathematical research is about, but I've no clue about physics. Can anyone suggest some reading (easy stuff) to get an idea of what theoretical physics is all about when it comes to research?

Comment: This [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_physics) could be a good start for you.

Comment: Go and talk and interview a theoretical physicist, then a mathematician; compare.

Comment: Note that "theoretical physics" is a rather broad term, as *every* subfield has theorists.

Comment: A very inspiring page that I read in my first year as an undergrad, and which I've glanced at since then every now and again, is Prof. 't Hooft's [How To Be A Good Theoretical Physicist](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html). It might give you an idea of some of the things that you will get to study. Depending on your country, a good Thoeretical Physics undergrad degree will expose you to most of it over four years, with the notable exception of QFT and String Theory.

Comment: Take a look at the five volumes of the Berkeley Series in Physics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Physics_Course